# Finding a relationship between x and y of a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-5y-xy}{-4x-xy}$$

How do I go about finding a relationship between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: You know what is meant by finding a relation?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I don't. If you do, please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-5y-xy}{-4x-xy} = \frac{y(x+ 5)}{x(y + 4)} = \dfrac{y}{y+4} \cdot \frac{x + 5}{x}$$

Now, the strong hint - This is a separable differential equation:

$$\dfrac{y+4}{y}\,dy \;\;= \;\dfrac{x+5}{x}\,dx$$

Comment: I see. I have solved and ended up with $y+4ln(y)=x+5ln(x)$. What if we were to specify initial conditions as well, let's say x(0)=5 and y(0)=10?

Comment: Hi Bob. Nice work. You also have a constant of integration: $$y + 4\ln y = x + 5\ln x + C$$ To determine the constant, we use the initial conditions: $x(0) = 5$, $y(0) = 10$: But here, those conditions are problematic, since $\ln 0$ is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- I really appreciate it. I've actually worked out a way to find out the constants with the provided initial conditions for anyone who is interested. 

$$ y + 4ln(y) = x + 5ln(x) + C $$
$$ ln(e^y) + ln(y^4) = ln(e^x) + ln(x^5) + C $$
$$ ln(e^yy^4)=ln(Ce^xx^5) $$
$$ e^yy^4=Ce^xx^5 $$
Plugging in x=5 and y=5 at t=0s:
$$(e^{10}10^4=Ce^55^5 $$
$$ C=\frac{e^{10}10^4}{e^5}{5^5} $$
$$ C=3.2e^{5} $$
Plugging back in C:
$$ (e^y)(y^4)=(3.2)(e^5)(e^x)(x^5) $$
$$ (e^y)(y^4)=3.2(e^{x+5})(e^x) $$